# How to access a text file from Assets in an android project and then search from it???

Tags: android

This Is what I am doing. Please Help me access my text file from my assets folder . And then i am searching an entered string from that text file???? But i am unable to do this...

```
    AssetManager re = getResources().getAssets();
            InputStream is = null;
        try {

            is = re.open("search.txt");
            if(is != null)
                new IconDownloader().execute("Test");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           


        //---------
        //read from file
        File file = new File("search.txt");
        try
        {   
            // File creating
            if(file.exists())
            {
                new IconDownloader().execute("Test");
                System.out.println("file exist");
                //new IconDownloader().execute("Test");
            }
            else
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            String word = tx3; int val = 0;

                //System.out.println("Enter the word to be searched for");
                //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                //word = input.next();
                Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("search.txt"));

                int v1=0;
                while(file1.hasNextLine()){
                    if(word.equals(file1.nextLine().trim()))
                    {
                        v1=1;
          //            new IconDownloader().execute("Test");
          //            System.out.println("Word exist");
                        break;
                     }
                }
                if(v1 == 0)
                    System.out.println("Word does not exist");

        }   
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    //-------------------------
```

//You can also mail me the answer on shahan_butt22@ucp.edu.pk thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You create the inputstream is from the asset manager but then never use it. File file = new File("Search.txt") which will look for the file in the default app directory! You also need to post the actual error you have and what IconDownloader.execute() does. This program at the moment opens an input stream to the correct file, create a txt file in the default directory and then searches the newly created file!
Try using this piece of code to read the text file

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String read = "";
    while((read = reader.readLine()) !=null)
    {
        //Do whatever you want to do to the line by checking string read
    }
```